# How do I save tweets in a CSV format with portuguese accentuation characters using python?

Tags: python, csv, tweepy

I am a student and I need to extract portuguese tweets saving they into a CSV table. The extraction works fine, as I can see in jupyter notebook, but when I create the CSV table, I get strange characters for the accentuated characters such as pr\xc3\xaamios.

Please, does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Below is the function code I am using.

```
import json
import re
import csv
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
```

#encoding: utf-8
def save_tweets( hashtag_phrase, api: tweepy.API):

```
#get the name of the spreadsheet we will write to
fname = '_'.join(re.findall(r"#(\w+)", hashtag_phrase))

#open the spreadsheet we will write to
with open('%s.csv' % (fname), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:

    
    w = csv.writer(file)

    #write header row to spreadsheet
    w.writerow(['timestamp', 'tweet_text', 'username', 'all_hashtags', 'followers_count'])

    #for each tweet matching our hashtags, write relevant info to the spreadsheet
    
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=hashtag_phrase+' -filter:retweets', tweet_mode='extended', result_type='mixed', lang='pt').items(50):
        w.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'), [e['text'] for e in tweet._json['entities']['hashtags']], tweet.user.followers_count])
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using ? If Python3, UTF8 encoding should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: don't `.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Hi... yes i am using Python 3,

Comment: I did like you suggest. When I eliminated the .encode(''utf-8') I got a different character  the word must be prémios but it appeared as prÃªmios., and with the utf-8 encode it appears as pr\xc3\xaamios.

Comment: the problem comes from your tweets then. please provide some examples

Comment: Here is a tweet that I extracted directly to jupyter notebook. O caso de marketing limpa a barra do #Carrefour ainda vai ganhar prêmios por aí. Impressionante. Com dinheiro vc consegue fazer praticamente qualquer coisa. Só não tá dando pra trazer mortos a vida mesmo...

Comment: Here is the same tweet extracted directly to a CSV table:  2021-11-12 14:46:03+00:00,O caso de marketing limpa a barra do #Carrefour ainda vai ganhar prÃªmios por aÃ­. Impressionante. Com dinheiro vc consegue fazer praticamente qualquer coisa. SÃ³ nÃ£o tÃ¡ dando pra trazer mortos a vida mesmo...

Comment: This problem only occurs when I try to save the tweet into a CSV table.

Answer (score 0):

`writerow` takes a list of... things. Those that are strings it uses "as is", those that aren't it converts to strings by calling `str()` on them. You are giving it the result from `.encode(...)`, which is a byte array, and `str()` on a byte array is rather useless in most cases.

Comment: Hi. I eliminated the .encode('utf-8') from my code, but the portuguese accentuated words still have strange characters to represent them. As example the word must be: Câmera, but it appears as: CÃ¢mera.  The portuguese words still aren't saved correctly in the csv table.

Comment: Those strange characters are what you get when a string is encoded as utf-8, and then decoded as iso-8859-1 (try typing `"Câmera".encode('utf-8').decode('iso-8859-1')` in an interactive Python session). Are you sure that the program displaying the CSV file knows that it is supposed to be reading utf-8?

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I was using Excel to open the csv table. When I used the notepad it worked fine.